# How can i add ImageView on RecyclerView 'list' on my 'main' page?

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-imageview, android-adapter

I've created a RecyclerView with an adapter but I need to create an ImageView with text but my 'main' page called 'TAGS' which only populate only  on my list!

But I need this page [This adapter make when the image has pressed the textview change the color!, but on my 'front-end which is my page called TAGS' can't 'add image with string'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcPba.png) Look at my **Public void di_tags** they add the same image LOL.

Can I add something like DICategorias.add("Astrologia", R.drawable.image1) or something with this list? or I need to create another list for the images for each position? or I need to create another recyclerview? Because [Thats is my 'View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_marca_tag_servico_layout, parent, false); layout from adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcPba.png) because if you see the first image the adapter add the same image... I need to add 45 images I just wanna know how I can add create a list with string and image 'concatenating' on my di_tags.

I tried to create an integer list on di_tags but not works. I just need an alternative like 'DICategorias.add("ASTROLOGIA") + R.drawable.image'.

[image]

[image]

**MY DI_TAGS.JAVA PAGE**

```
public class DITags extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter2.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

RecyclerView DICategoriasRecyclerView;
RecyclerViewAdapter2 recyclerViewAdapter2;
List<String> DICategorias;
ArrayList<Integer> array_image;
private Button DIBotaoContinuarTag;
int selectedItemCount;
Bundle bundle;
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> DICategoriasData = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
private List<String> listResult = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<TagsModel> taglista = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //=============================

    ArrayList<String> Arquitetura = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(0, Arquitetura);

    ArrayList<String> Astrologia = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(1, Astrologia);

    ArrayList<String> Atualidades = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(2, Atualidades);

    ArrayList<String> Autoconhecimento = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(3, Autoconhecimento);

    ArrayList<String> Automotores = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(4, Automotores);

    ArrayList<String> Beleza = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(5, Beleza);

    ArrayList<String> Casamento = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(6, Casamento);

    ArrayList<String> Decoracao = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(7, Decoracao);

    ArrayList<String> Dicas = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(8, Dicas);

    ArrayList<String> Diversao = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(9, Diversao);

    ArrayList<String> Educacao = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(10, Educacao);

    ArrayList<String> Empreendedorismo = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(11, Empreendedorismo);

    ArrayList<String> Esportes = new ArrayList<String>();
    DICategoriasData.put(12, Esportes);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ditags);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    di_tags();
    di_tags1();
    DICategoriasRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.DICategoriasRecyclerView);
    selectedItemCount = 0;

    recyclerViewAdapter2 = new RecyclerViewAdapter2(DICategorias, this);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

    DIBotaoContinuarTag = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DIBotaoContinuarTag);

    DIBotaoContinuarTag.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDIContinuarTag();
        }
    });

    DICategoriasRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter2);
}

public void di_tags1() {
    // TagsDaMarcaData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // ARQUITETURA fica na posição 0
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("ARQUITETURA", R.drawable.categorias_arquitetura));

    // ASTROLOGIA fica na posição 1
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("ASTROLOGIA", R.drawable.categorias_astrologia));

    // ATUALIDADES fica na posição 2
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("ATUALIDADES", R.drawable.categorias_atualidades));

    // AUTOCONHECIMENTO fica na posição 3
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("AUTOCONHECIMENTO", R.drawable.categorias_autoconhecimento));

    // AUTOMOTORES fica na posição 4
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("AUTOMOTORES", R.drawable.categorias_automotores));

    // BELEZA fica na posição 5
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("BELEZA", R.drawable.categorias_beleza));

    // CASAMENTO fica na posição 6
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("CASAMENTO", R.drawable.categorias_casamento));

    // DECORAÇÃO fica na posição 7
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("DECORAÇÃO", R.drawable.categorias_decoracao));

    // DICAS fica na posição 8
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("DICAS", R.drawable.categorias_dicas));

    // DIVERSÕES fica na posição 9
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("DIVERSÕES", R.drawable.categorias_diversao));

    // EDUCAÇÃO fica na posição 10
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("EDUCAÇÃO", R.drawable.categorias_educacao));

    // EMPREENDEDORISMO fica na posição 11
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("EMPREENDEDORISMO", R.drawable.categorias_empreendedorismo));

    // ENTRETENIMENTO fica na posição 12
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("ENTRETENIMENTO", R.drawable.categorias_entretenimento));

    // ESPORTES fica na posição 13
    taglista.add(new TagsModel("ESPORTES", R.drawable.categorias_esportes));
}

public void di_tags() {
    DICategorias = new ArrayList<String>();
    // TagsDaMarcaData = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // ARQUITETURA fica na posição 0
    DICategorias.add("ARQUITETURA");

    // ASTROLOGIA fica na posição 1
    DICategorias.add("ASTROLOGIA");

    // ATUALIDADES fica na posição 2
    DICategorias.add("ATUALIDADES");

    // AUTOCONHECIMENTO fica na posição 3
    DICategorias.add("AUTOCONHECIMENTO");

    // AUTOMOTORES fica na posição 4
    DICategorias.add("AUTOMOTORES");

    // BELEZA fica na posição 5
    DICategorias.add("BELEZA");

    // CASAMENTO fica na posição 6
    DICategorias.add("CASAMENTO");

    // DECORAÇÃO fica na posição 7
    DICategorias.add("DECORAÇÃO");

    // DICAS fica na posição 8
    DICategorias.add("DICAS");

    // DIVERSÕES fica na posição 9
    DICategorias.add("DIVERSÕES");

    // EDUCAÇÃO fica na posição 10
    DICategorias.add("EDUCAÇÃO");

    // EMPREENDEDORISMO fica na posição 11
    DICategorias.add("EMPREENDEDORISMO");

    // ESPORTES fica na posição 12
    DICategorias.add("ESPORTES");
}


public void openDIContinuarTag() {
    SparseBooleanArray asd = recyclerViewAdapter2.sparseBooleanArray;
    ArrayList<String> ListaFinal = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListaFinal.clear();
    final int checkedItemCount = asd.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedItemCount; i++) {  // loop em todos os items... mas o Toast Sobrescreve a outra mensagem.
        int key = asd.keyAt(i);
        if (asd.get(key)) {
            List<String> ListResult = DICategoriasData.get(key);

            ListaFinal.add(String.valueOf(key));
            for (int z = 0; z < (ListResult.size()); z++) { // Faz o Loop dentro de todos os itens da sublista
                String asdasd = ListResult.get(z);
                ListaFinal.add(asdasd);

            }

        } else {
            // item was in the sparse array, but not checked.
        }
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DISubCategorias.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Result", ListaFinal);
    startActivity(intent);


}

// quando o usuário clicar no item na lista RecyclerView, nosso adaptador criado invocará a seguinte função e passará a posição.
@Override
public void selectedItemCount(int count) {
    selectedItemCount = count;
  }


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
 }

}
```

**MY RecyclerViewAdapter2**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder> {

List<String> TagsDaMarca;
List<String> SubServicoTagsDaMarca;
List<String> DICategorias;

HashMap<Integer, List<String>> ListaCatSubCat = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
public static SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray;
// for identifying: in list which items are selected
OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener;
int meutotal = 0;


public RecyclerViewAdapter2(List<String> TagsDaMarca1, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {
    TagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    SubServicoTagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    DICategorias = TagsDaMarca1;


    sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_marca_tag_servico_layout, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String item = DICategorias.get(position);

    if (item.equals("0")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("ARQUITETURA");
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_arquitetura);
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);

    } else if (item.equals("1")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("ASTROLOGIA");
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_astrologia);
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("2")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("ATUALIDADES");
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_atualidades);
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("3")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("AUTOCONHECIMENTO");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_autoconhecimento);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("4")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("AUTOMOTORES");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_automotores);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("5")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("BELEZA");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_beleza);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("6")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("CASAMENTO");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_casamento);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("7")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("DECORAÇÃO");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_decoracao);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("8")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("DICAS");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_dicas);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("9")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("DIVERSÕES");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_diversao);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("10")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("EDUCAÇÃO");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_educacao);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("11")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("EMPREENDEDORISMO");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(R.drawable.sub_categorias_empreendedorismo);
        holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
        holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
    } else if (item.equals("12")) {
        holder.itemTextView.setText("ESPORTES");
        holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      else {
        holder.itemTextView.setText(item);
        if (sparseBooleanArray.get(position)) {
            holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
        } else {
            holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(190, 190, 190));
        }

    }

    //holder.itemTextView.setText(SubTagsDaMarca.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (TagsDaMarca != null) {
        return TagsDaMarca.size();
    }else if (SubServicoTagsDaMarca != null) {
        return SubServicoTagsDaMarca.size();
    }else if (DICategorias != null) {
        return DICategorias.size();
    }
    return 0;
}


/******** View Holder Class*/
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView itemTextView;
    ImageView DICategoriasIcones;
    public TextView alert;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        itemTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        DICategoriasIcones = itemView.findViewById(R.id.DICategoriasIcones);
        DICategoriasIcones.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (!sparseBooleanArray.get(getAdapterPosition())) {
            if (meutotal < 3) {
                sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
                meutotal = meutotal + 1;
            }
        } else // if clicked item is already selected
        {
            sparseBooleanArray.put(getAdapterPosition(), false);
            notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
            meutotal = meutotal - 1;
        }
    }
}


public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    public void selectedItemCount(int count);
}

public class SubCategoriasHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public SubCategoriasHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
  }
}
```

On my DITags.java i have another list which is 'subcategories' from every category and i pass 'subcategories' with `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Result", ListaFinal);` for another intent which is the subcategories part.

And i have this loop for limit user by maximum 3 categories[image: That's What I Want]

Answer (score 0):

**First create a model class like this**

```
public class TagsModel {

String name;
int images;

public TagsModel(String name, int images) {
    this.name = name;
    this.images = images;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getImages() {
    return images;
}

public void setImages(int images) {
    this.images = images;
}
}
```

**Then declare an Arraylist in TAG_Activity like this**

```
    ArrayList<TagsModel> taglist = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Then add data to this ArrayList like this**

```
public void di_tags() {
    taglist.add(new TagsModel("data1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    taglist.add(new TagsModel("data1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    taglist.add(new TagsModel("data1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    taglist.add(new TagsModel("data1", R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
}
```

**At last pass taglist to your adapter**

```
Your_Adapter adp = new Your_Adapter(getApplicationContext(), taglist);
Your_recyclerview.setAdapter(adp );
adp .notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Also don't forget to change Datatype in adapter to TagsModel**

**RecyclerViewAdapter2.java** changes in your adapter like this

```
  ArrayList<TagsModel> TagsDaMarca;//change like this
ArrayList<TagsModel> SubServicoTagsDaMarca;//change like this
ArrayList<TagsModel> DICategorias;//change like this

HashMap<Integer, List<String>> ListaCatSubCat = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
public static SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray;
// for identifying: in list which items are selected
OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener;
int meutotal = 0;


public RecyclerViewAdapter2(ArrayList<TagsModel> TagsDaMarca1, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {
    TagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    SubServicoTagsDaMarca = TagsDaMarca1;
    DICategorias = TagsDaMarca1;


    sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_marca_tag_servico_layout, parent, false);
    return new RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter2.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    TagsModel item = DICategorias.get(position);//change like this
holder.itemTextView.setText(item.getName());
    holder.DICategoriasIcones.setImageResource(item.getImages());
    holder.itemTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    holder.itemTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 167));
    holder.DICategoriasIcones.setEnabled(false);
    holder.itemTextView.setEnabled(false);
```

Now try calling **item.getName() **for string and **item.getImages()** for images

Comment: I'm getting the error `RecyclerViewAdapter2
(java.util.List<java.lang.String>,
com.example.fqrgotten.RecyclerViewAdapter2.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener)
in RecyclerViewAdapter2 cannot be applied
to
(android.content.Context,
java.util.ArrayList<com.example.fqrgotten.TagsModel>`

Comment: When i put 'taglist.add(new TagsModel("ARQUITETURA", "R.drawable.image1")); i getting another error `TagsModel
(String,
int)
in TagsModel cannot be applied
to
(String,
java.lang.String)`

Comment: @PinhaDooido remove double quotes   "R.drawable.image1" and put it as i said above. drawable image type is integer not string

Comment: @PinhaDooido please show the code where error occur

Comment: I will edit my question with adapter to understand better.

Comment: @PinhaDooido i understand your issue show your adapter . you need to change ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Tagmodel> in adapter

Comment: Look at my edit. you will understand why i have this 'issues' with multiple list.

Comment: @PinhaDooido can you say where is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Look at the third image on my question!, my image on the first categories is not showing... only shows on subcategories... but when i 'populate' the di_tags with <string> only, they showing all strings normaly!, and you said to create a 'model class' but the image and the string is not appear... i don't know why :'(

Comment: @PinhaDooido i am confused . can you specify what you you need so i can help you

Comment: I recorded a video !, I think it will be very explaining!... this when I use only strings on my 'di_tags(); [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlhfDn8Da5s) **They pass all the strings but the image is all the same**  and that's happens when i use the 'model class' [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9oZlMEhVLlo) **I just wanna know how can i pass string and image because the model class** is not working. @JinsLukose

Comment: If you see in the first video, the image is all the same **how can i set the image and strings?** and on video you will see error on my adapter!. I can use multiple array on adapter like this? `public RecyclerViewAdapter2(ArrayList<TagsModel> TagsModel, List<String> TagsStrings, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener listener) {

        TagsDaMarca = TagsStrings;
        SubServicoTagsDaMarca = TagsStrings;
        DICategorias = TagsStrings;

        taglista = TagsModel;

        sparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
        this.listener = listener;
    }`

Comment: @PinhaDooido check my updated answer **RecyclerViewAdapter2.java**

Comment: On 'TagsModel item = DICategorias.get(position);' i getting the warning `equals()' between objects of inconvertible types 'TagsModel' and 'String' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Reports calls to .equals() where the target and argument are of incompatible types. While such a call might theoretically be useful, most likely it represents a bug` and on `holder.itemTextView.setText(item);` i getting the error `Cannot resolve method 'setText(com.example.fqrgotten.sollerdigital.TagsModel)`

Comment: @PinhaDooido why are you using this condition  if (item.equals("0")) {
}else if (item.equals("1")) {
} **Instead use like check the edit above  after**   TagsModel item = DICategorias.get(position);

Comment: I need those `condition if (item.equals("0")) { }else if (item.equals("1")) ` for change the color of image and textview onClick. and you said **Instead use like check the edit above after** it worked!. but i can't change the color onClick thats why i use those **condition**

Comment: I think its because i use the same adapter for Subcategories page... can i use another adapter for Subcategories.java?, and on Categories.java page and pass the `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Result", ListaFinal);` to retrive those value from Categories.java?.

Comment: @PinhaDooido yes i think you should use two adapters

Comment: And on **TagsModel** i need to use `implements Parcelable` to retrive data for another by using `i.putExtra("Result", TagsModel);`right?

Comment: @PinhaDooido Implement serializable that's easy

Comment: @PinhaDooido better you close this question. if any more doubt ask another question